# "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" with Zend Framework 1 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I am writing script to update the tables `Customer`, `Contact` and `User`:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 
  1452 Cannot add or update a child row: 
  a foreign key constraint fails 
(`bat`.`contact`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Contact` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`customerid`) REFERENCES `customer` (`idCustomer`) 
   ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) `
```

CustomController.php

```
public function addCustomer(array $data)
{
    //var_dump($data);
    if(!empty($data))
    {

        $Customer = new Admin_Model_DbTable_Customer();
        $customerid = $Customer->fetchRow($Customer->select()->where('intra = ?',  $data['intra']));
        if( $customerid->idCustomer > 0){


            $this->update($data, array('intra = ?' => $data['intra']));
            echo  "UPDATE ". $data['intra'];
            return true;

        } else {

            $row = $this->createRow();
            $row->intra                 =   $data['intra'];
            $row->fabname               =   $data['fabname'];
            $row->namecustomer          =   $data['namecustomer'];
            $row->adresse               =   $data['adresse'];           
            $row->city                  =   $data['city'];          
            $row->zipcode               =   $data['zipcode'];           
            $row->country               =   $data['country'];           
            $row->phone                 =   $data['phone'];     
            $row->representative        =   $data['representative'];
            $row->idUser                =   $data['idUser'];
            $lastId = $row->save();


            echo  "LAST ID = $lastId";
            return $lastId;

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the update statement which caused the error? (BTW this has nothing to do with Zend Framework)

Comment: i added thanks in advance i have always this error : Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key

Answer (score 1):

When you define a foreign key, there is some restriction for `update` `delete` `insert` `join` operations depend on your design. this restriction help you to have valid data in your database.
But if you want to force query to commit `update` `delete` `insert` `join`, you can use

> $Customer->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false); // Just for `join`

Or add

> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = FALSE; // For all queries

before your query.

Another solution is find the integrity problem. for example you may want to `update` or `insert` a row and set foreign key to a value that does not exist in reference table.

Comment: always i have this error :Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails i added $Customer->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $this->update($data, array('intra = ?' => $data['intra']));

Comment: may be you try to update a foreign key to a value that does not exist in reference table? can you give us your db schema, data and print_r($data) output?